# Prestashop top horizontal menu disappears

Tags: prestashop

I am using the basic template of prestashop.  I cannot find top horizontal menu - which I can find other basic template of prestashop.  How to make this module appears?

I only can find horizontal menu.  This is strange?  How to make the top horizontal menu appears?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is one default module . in default module in ps1.7.x  is **Main menu**
ps 1.6.x is **Top horizontal menu** .So there no different module **horizontal menu** or  **top horizontal menu**.

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

You need check if the module "**blocktopmenu**" is hooked on the hook "**displayTop**" in **module > position**. If not, just click on **"Transplant a module"**, choose the module in the dropdown and the hook displayTop and it should appear on you website after saving.

You can also try to reset the module in **module and services > blocktopmenu > reset** if the first solution does not work.